# Do all nonzero binary matrices have its spectral radius as a simple eigenvalue?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Do all nonzero binary matrices have its spectral radius as a simple eigenvalue? The Perron Theorem tells us that the statement is true for all positive or irreducible matrices, but I want to know if this is true in general if we are limited to nonzero binary matrices.

Is it still true if the nonzero binary matrix is symmetric?

What if we add the constraint that at most $\frac{1}{4}$ of the entries are $0$?

Thanks, I appreciate any help on these problems.

Comment: The $2\times 2$ identity matrix has its spectral radius, 1, as a double eigenvalue.

Comment: What if we add the constraint that at most $\frac{1}{4}$ of the entries are $0$? Does that change anything?

Comment: Do we still have $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1& 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$  to worry about?